# Solve PMT Equation to get the rate

Tags: microsoft-excel, equations

I'm turning to you after using all my resources and being blocked on a mathematical issue.

In the context of a system migration, I have to transfer data to a new system and perform calculation. I have a table in SQL containing data about a loan.

Each lines is a loan and contains the PMT, PV, FV and the duration of the loan (in month)

What needs to be done is calculating the interest rate.

It is easily done by using the RATE function, both on SQL and Excel ( I use Excel to isolate cases and do check because the RATE and PMT function of excel is the same in SQL)

But I have been told that some cases are note completely accurate in my calculation using the rate function.

The reason is that fore some cases, the payment is not constant, where the first period contains an extra payment

Here is one of the case that contains the issue:

I have to calculate the rate for a function having 2 different PMT over a period 60 months

- PMT first months : 5426.62
- PMT 59 next months : 403.17
- PV:30750.87
- FV:7235.5

I was blocked at this stage, because how can I use the rate function with different PMT?

After that, I asked them to provide me with the algorithm used by their system to perform the calculation, and here is the equation they use:

[image: Formula]

formula's arguments :

- PMT= 403.17
- I= 36177,49
- X= 5426,62
- Y= 7235,5
- d= 60
- r= ?

So, from this formula, I have to isolate r

Is there a way to solve this?

Many thanks for reading

Comment: What work have you done?  Payment = PV times Interest (adjust for Period).   FV is reduced by the capital part of the Payment .  Do some work with this.

Comment: Hi @john, Thanks for replying. Could you be more specific ? What else is needed here?

Comment: That is the work in the course you are doing.  There are lots of resources to do the financial calculations.

Comment: I have been looking around quite a lot, and didn’t find a formula to calculate the rate when having 2 different PMT. Which ressources are you thinking of?

Comment: Here is something to get you started:  https://www.coursehero.com/file/p470jgtp/Principal-X-Interest-Rate-X-Time-Simple-Interest-4-Quarterly-Payment-60000-X6/

Comment: sounds like you need to sit down with paper and pencil and figure out how to manipulate the equations to solve your problem before you even think about figuring out how to use excel to do this calculation for you...

Comment: Yes @gns100 that’s where I’m a big stuck at the moment, did many manipulation on paper all day, but still stuck at some point when it comes to isolating the ‘r’, and I don’t have a huge mathematical background

Comment: Take a mortgage of 100,000, and an Interest rate of 3% and reduce the mortgage monthly over 12 months and see what principal is left over at the end of 12 months.

Comment: This is a math issue, not a problem using computer hardware or software. You've tagged as "Microsoft excel" bit there are no formulae or example tables showing your data.

Comment: @Mokubai I just extracted one line of my data, because if it works for one line, then same solution will apply to the rest. I've tagged Excel because I'm performing the calculations in Excel and SQL

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Rearranging mathematical equations would not be within the scope of this site, though actually implementing an equation *might* be if you showed us your working and what you have so far. That you are blocked on mathematics does not immediately make a question suitable for their site on topic here and just saying "I'm doing it in excel and sql" is not proof that it is on topic. There is nothing in your current question that is on topic at this moment. It sound like you need more experience on rearranging mathematical formulae.

Comment: @Mokubai I have edited my post providing more context. I tried to avoid it because of DNA, but should be fine that way, I hope it's correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The "simple answer" is that you have to run the `RATE` function twice, or however many times is needed. You'll have to store the PMT and duration for each stage.

Then you effectively run

```
(PMT1 x Duration1) + (PMT2 x Duration2) + (PMT... x Duration...)
```

You will probably also have to subtract out the value taken for earlier stages from the PMT caclulation of later stages, which will complicate your formula.

There is really no other easy way around it. If the PMTs change then you have to deal with them separately, if the PMT never changes then you can simply set `PMT2` etc to `0` and the rest of the equations will cancel out and simply add `0` on each stage.